# The heroku cli fails

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I run

```
heroku logs
```

and get

```
'ENOCOMMANDS': semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
```

Is there a problem with the current version of heroku?  I have searched for both ENOCOMMANDS and semver with no useful results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by uninstalling and then installing heroku like this...

$brew uninstall --force heroku
$rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku ~/.config/heroku ~/Library/Caches/heroku

$brew install heroku

Comment: I had to do something similar on Ubuntu after getting the same errors. Took a while and trying a few different commands to get rid of it, and reinstall heroku-cli/6.15.13-1 over 6.15.11.1, but it worked eventually.